# Will this computer fullfill my expectations?

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, processor, pc, ssd

I want to buy a new pc soon and want to build it myself. Now I figured out the components I want to use. Could you tell me, whether everything fits together and if I can get something better for the same price (so if there is a better or newer component for the same price)? Thanks in advance.

CPU: i7-4790k

Mainboard: MSI B85-G41 PC Mate (especially here I'm not fure whether my graphic card i chose will fit on the mainboard)

CPU cooler: Thermaltake Contac 21

RAM: G.Skill DIMM 32 GB DDR4-2133 Kit

Graphic card: Sapphire AMD Radeon R9 390 OC Tri-X NITRO

SSD: Samsung 850 EVO 1 TB

Case: Sharkoon VS4-W

Power supply: Thermaltake Berlin 630W

Fans: 2 x be quiet! Silent Wings 2 120 mm (is this needed?)

And of course a CD-drive and Windows 8.1 on it.

Sorry to not ne able to post links, as I do not have 10 reputation yet.

Comment: What we really need to know is what you're using it for. Breaking the question into individual components is also standard practice on this site.

Comment: It's for gaming.... What do you mean with breaking into individual components?

Comment: Break up into CPU, MB, RAM, GPU, storage etc and ask for recommendations on each one, with a given budget for the part, though if you can give one for the whole computer on every question, it'll be helpful as well. Be specific as to what games you want to play and which country you live in, etc, etc. Tell us the part you've looked at, any concerns you might have. That's pretty much all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about compatibility issues and build reviews are not in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Most important question is what is your budget and what will you use it for ?

Also I have some doubts about your setup and I will list them below changing some elements to "better" or "compatible":

1.Why Haswell not Skylake ?

If you are thinking about so strong setup you should think about newest platform (Skylake) and change CPU and Motherboard.

- [Intel Core i7-6700K](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819117559) ~$380
- [ASUS Z170 Pro Gaming](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813132567) ~$155

You should also change your RAM memory to higher frequency. RAM listed below is good example:

- [G.SKILL Ripjaws V Series 32GB (4 x 8GB)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820232223&cm_re=gskill-_-20-232-223-_-Product)

2.If it is your intetion to stay with Haswell you have few parts which won't fit in your setup.

- CPU/Motherboard - You want to buy so good CPU with OC possibility (letter K at the end of CPU ) but your motherboard won't give you OC possibility. There are two ways to change it. First you can buy Motherboard with Z97 chipset to have OC possibility (for example [MSI Z97 Gaming 5](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813130770) ~$135). If you want to stay without OC possibility you should change i7-4690K to i7-4690.
- RAM which you choosed is not compatible with your Motherboard (it is DDR4 and your motherboard uses DDR3) so you should choose something like this: [Crucial Ballistix Tactical 32GB (4 x 8GB)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820148659).

3.If this build is prepared for gaming I would buy maximum of 16GB RAM it will be enough for a long time.

4.If you are thinking about OC in setup with this GPU and CPU I would buy a little better PSU, for example [XFX TS Series P1 750W](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817207033&cm_re=XFX_TS_750W-_-17-207-033-_-Product)

5.Fans. They will be needed If you decide to overclock your setup.

Comment: Thank you for that.. Maybe I really will use Skylake instead of Haswell...And yes, computer should be for gaming, so I will only buy 16gb then... And with better PSU, do you meen more watt or better efficiency? I don't plan to overclock that computer.... What do you think about the r9 390? Budget is like in my configuration, so $1400...

Comment: @user5638730 Personally if this setup is for gaming and won't be overclocked I would go with i5-6600 (without K letter), little worse motherboard and less RAM memory (16 GB) and change R9 390 to GTX980 or GTX980Ti.

Comment: But GTX980 is about $200 more expensive, is it worth it?

Comment: @user5638730 Actually I think that upgrade to GTX 980Ti is worth it for sure and upgrade to GTX980 is a little bit less effective but if you are buying new GPU I would go with GTX980 for this $200 bigger price. You should still have in mind that in the nearest future Nvidia and AMD will present their new GPU's maybe it's worth to wait for this.